# How to delete directories based on `find` output: ONLY the first result

Tags: find, exec, delete

Based on this question,

[How to delete directories based on `find` output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89925/how-to-delete-directories-based-on-find-output)

I tried to remove only the first folder of result doing:

```
find * -type d | head -n1 | -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But I receive this error:

```
bash: -exec: command not found
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `-exec` is a flag to `find` the `|` is a "pipe" between commands that connects the output of one command to the input of the next. So after the pipe is a separate command.

Comment: Similar recent confusion: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495361/117549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-quit` after using `-delete` or `-exec`:

> **-quit**
>   Exit  immediately.   No  child  processes will be left running, but no more paths specified on the command line will be processed.

---

Deleting the first result of your `find` command:

```
find * -type d -exec rm -Rf {} \; -quit
```

or

```
find . ! -path . -type d -exec rm -Rf {} \; -quit
```

The latter will find hidden folders.

---

> Note, that your find output may [not be sorted alphabetically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34325/sorting-the-output-of-find).

For deletion of first result afer sorting:

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | head -zn1 | xargs -r0 rm -Rf
```

For numeric sort, use `sort -zn`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! so I'll add "sort -z", but I'll have the same problem of | head -n1, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

pLumo has adequately given a few good alternative solutions [in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495794/116858).  I'm providing a totally different approach.

You will notice that the `find` command, the way you're using it with `*` describing the top-level search paths, is only really used for *finding the first directory among the names that `*` expands to*.

You may do this with a shell loop too, which results in code that is easier to read and to see what it does:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for name in *; do
    if [ -d "$name" ] && [ ! -h "$name" ]; then
        rm -rf -- "$name"
        break
    fi
done
```

This loop, which assumes it's running in a `bash` shell, iterates over all names matched by `*` (including hidden names).  The body of the loop tests whether the current name is a directory (without being a symbolic link to a directory), and if so deletes the directory recursively before exiting the loop.

A similar effect could be had in the `zsh` shell with the much simpler command

```bsh
rm -rf -- *(D/[1])
```

This removes the first directory that `*` expands to.  The globbing qualifier `(D/[1])` restricts the match of `*` to only directories (`/`), but includes hidden names (`D`), and returns only the first matching name (`[1]`).  If there are no directories in the current directory, you would get a "no matches found" error message from the shell.

Answer (score -1):

This seems very dangerous but you could try:

```
find * -type d | head -n1 | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Indeed dangerous. Having`>$ ls:     important_file important_file\nfake_folder`, your command will delete `very_important_file`. Better use `find -print0` and `head -z` and `xargs -0`.

Answer (score -1):

for me worked this code:

- finds ONLY the files  with -type f,
- filter files not containing ".gz"
- select N files in this case ONLY FIRST ONE -n 1

code:

find . -type f ! -name "*.gz" | head -n 1 | xargs rm -rf {} ;

Comment: This seems to solve a different problem. Note that the user uses `*` as the search path. This means their `find` command will never (or should never) recurse into directories.